# Unity failed to build android apk ! it is about too many files in SteamingAssets folder

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

After investigation, fail's reason is too many files in SteamingAssets folder!

I try put totle 679 files into SteamAssets folder, it will build succuful.
but i try put totle 680 files and then build fail.

I make sure all files extension are same and it does not limited by file size.

How to fix it ?

*Unity Version:2020.3.1f*

*System Version: Windows 7*

**Fail Stack:**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity2020\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:unity-android-resources:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED
57 actionable tasks: 25 executed, 32 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <0c3742f371b24679bcaa6fcc508d0cca>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know how to fix it!

1, Edit -> Player Setting -> Publishing Settings, click "Custom Base Gradle Template" blew the Build section.

2, You will find a "Assets\Plugins\Android\baseProjectTemplate.gradle" file was generated, open it by text editor.

3, change
"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'"
into
"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'"

Build again, and don't forget to add it to your CVS.

If you get solved and like this solution, please do me a favor to mark a star for this repo:

[enter link description here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-build-fails-when-there-are-680-or-more-files-in-the-streaming-assets-folder?_gl=1*nr31dr*_ga*MTQ3MzgxNzU2OC4xNTk5NjQwNjQ3*_ga_1S78EFL1W5*MTYyMjQ3MjIxMC43LjEuMTYyMjQ3NDA1Ny42MA..&_ga=2.214254871.1828782313.1622375327-1473817568.1599640647)